# How to save pandas DataFrame's rows as JSON strings?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` and I convert each row to JSON string as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_as_json = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Then  I want to iterate over the JSON strings (rows) of `df_as_json` and make further processing as follows:

```
for json_document in df_as_json.split('\n'):
    jdict = json.loads(json_document)
    //...
```

The problem is that `df_as_json.split('\n')` does not really split `df_as_json` into separate JSON strings.

How can I do what I need?

Comment: So you want each row of the dataframe as a dict?

Comment: You could try to print your `df_as_json`. It contains square bracket and has no `\n` so it won't work. @StephenRauch's solution should be perfect for your case.

Comment: @PangeranBottor Nope, if you want to save a JSON file as JSON lines, then `to_json` supports a `lines=True` argument. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48243775/4909087).

Comment: For some reason `lines=True` was not working for me. I was getting an error about unknown argument.

Comment: @Markus You have to update your pandas version. Latest stable release is 0.22.

Comment: @Markus From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html), the `lines` argument is new with version 0.19. You should also be aware of the fact that using the API is much faster than looping yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get each row of the dataframe as a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

#### Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
for jdict in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    print(jdict)
```

#### Results:

```
{'A': -0.81155648424969018, 'B': 0.54051722275060621, 'C': 2.1858014972680886, 'D': -0.92089743800379931}
{'A': -0.051650790117511704, 'B': -0.79176498452586563, 'C': -0.9181773278020231, 'D': 1.1698955805545324}
{'A': -0.59790963665018559, 'B': -0.63673166723131003, 'C': 1.0493603533698836, 'D': 1.0027811601157812}
{'A': -0.20909149867564752, 'B': -1.8022674158328837, 'C': 1.0849019267782165, 'D': 1.2203116471260997}
{'A': 0.33798033123267207, 'B': 0.13927004774974402, 'C': 1.6671536830551967, 'D': 0.29193412587056755}
{'A': -0.079327003827824386, 'B': 0.58625181818942929, 'C': -0.42365912798153349, 'D': -0.69644626255641828}
{'A': 0.33849577559616656, 'B': -0.42955248285258169, 'C': 0.070860788937864225, 'D': 1.4971679265264808}
{'A': 1.3411846077264038, 'B': -0.20189961315847924, 'C': 1.6294881274421233, 'D': 1.1168181183218009}
{'A': 0.61028134135655399, 'B': 0.48445766812257018, 'C': -0.31117315672299928, 'D': -1.7986688463810827}
{'A': 0.9181074339928279, 'B': 0.84151139156427757, 'C': -1.111794854210024, 'D': -0.7131446510569609}
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting from v0.19, you can use [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) with `lines=True` parameter to save your data as a [JSON *lines* file](http://jsonlines.org/).

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

This eliminates the need for a loop to save each record, as a solution with `to_dict` would involve.

The first 5 lines of `file.json` look like this -

```
{"A":0.0162261253,"B":0.8770884013,"C":0.1577913843,"D":-0.3097990255}
{"A":-1.2870077735,"B":-0.1610902061,"C":-0.2426829569,"D":-0.3247587907}
{"A":-0.7743891125,"B":-0.9487264737,"C":1.6366125588,"D":0.2943377348}
{"A":1.5128287075,"B":-0.389437321,"C":0.4841038875,"D":0.5315466818}
{"A":-0.1455759399,"B":1.0205229385,"C":0.6776108196,"D":0.832060379}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is

```
input_data=[row.to_json() for index,row in dataset.iterrows()]
```